# Device Pin before installing APK

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

My use case is, My app should verify the device pin/password is set. if not then enforce the user to set it up. This has to be performed every time user launches my application and proceed after verification of the pin/password. Can some please help how to implement this. I am using apache cordova and jquery for my application development.

Comment: it would certainly look like your app is trying to gain knowledge of that pin/password.

Comment: no. the intention is to make sure the device is setup with password before installing the app.

Answer (score 0):

This would be plausible if there were, say, a manifest permission you could add since Android checks the permissions before installing the app, but there isn't that option... Personally, I wouldn't enter my phones "master password" into an app. Too sketchy. Your best option is to create your own password system handled by your app. So whenever the app is run (or whatever your specific need is) you can ask the user to input his password.